# Buttons in a wx.ListCtrl in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, listctrl

I want to know if it is possible to incorporate Buttons in a ListCtrl in report mode on each line in a column.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the UltimateListCtrl, then yes. The normal ListCtrl widget does not support that.